# I can't log in to a project in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

What to do I'm doing a project with a friend and I'm throwing him the project files, he opens the project and shows this error in Unity Hub, this did not happen before, and after one moment it began to appear, I don't have such an error, the Internet is almost empty about it. What to do?

[nice error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9tWJ.png)

I solved the problem, I just needed to create a new folder for projects

Comment: The file is locked by a process.  Close unity, source control, anything that could touch that file.  Then click retry.

Comment: Check hes also not putting them into an area covered by apple or google drive

Comment: Are you using version control or are you simply copying files from one computer to the next?  In any event, close Unity, delete the **Library** folder and re-open the project.

Comment: i simply copying project from one computer to the next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I just needed to create a new folder for projects

Answer (score 0):

There are  some solutions online eg. [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-access-database-locked-library-artifactdb-error.1216515/)
It seems like one possible solution is related to the Crash Handler or related to git VC.

One simple common solution is

> One interim test solution is to try copying the Assets/ and ProjectSettings/ and Packages/ file to a brand new directory somewhere, then try opening that.

Comment: but how to do the same as that guy with Git, otherwise the method that at the end of the page did not work(

I just don't know how to use git. What is git VC??How do I drag it all there?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).